# Cannot convert value of type 'Range<String.Index>?' to specified type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange')

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am getting below error during Objective-C to Swift code change. Thanks

```
func combinedName() -> String? {
        let range: NSRange = name.range(of: brand)
        if Int(range.length) > 0 {
            return name
        }
        return "\(brand) \(name)"
    }
```

[image: error]

My Objective-C code

```
- (NSString *)combinedName {
    NSRange range = [self.name rangeOfString:self.brand];
    if (range.length > 0) return self.name;
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.brand, self.name];
}
```

Comment: Basically don't annotate types the compiler can infer. You are making it worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't directly translate Objective-C code. Write it from scratch as Swift code using normal Swift constructs.

```
func combinedName() -> String {
    if name.range(of: brand) != nil {
        return name
    } else {
        return "\(brand) \(name)"
    }
}
```

Assuming both `name` and `brand` are not optional, the return type shouldn't be optional because you don't return `nil` under any circumstances.

You can also make the code simpler using `?:`:

```
func combinedName() -> String {
    return name.range(of: brand) != nil ? name : "\(brand) \(name)"
}
```

Comment: Or, in this case, just `if name.contains(brand)`

Comment: @MartinR Good call. Though I tend to use `range` with `options` when I don't want an exact match. `contains` is certainly easier here though.